# Free dynamic memory with free()

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, free

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char **last_names;
    // last_names has been assigned a char * array of length 4. Each element of the array has
    // been assigned a char array of length 20.
    //
    // All of these memory has been allocated on the heap.
    // Free all of the allocated memory (hint: 5 total arrays).


    return 0;
}
```

I know the free() method and this is my approach;

```
free(*last_names);
free(last_names);
```

but it's not true.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Rather than describe your allocation, show it in the code.

Comment: Please add code that (1) allocates `last_names`, and (2) allocates individual elements to `last_names`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your description of the code, your memory allocation would be:

```
last_names = malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    last_names[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
```

So deallocation should be done as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    free(last_names[i]);
free(last_names);
```